# When should I call Twitter Bootstrap methods on HTML code dynamically added by Emberjs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using **Emberjs**, **handlebars** and **Twitter Bootstrap**. In my `handlebars` template, I'm using a Twitter Boostrap `dropdown`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="dropdown">
        {{#each content}}
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                <i class="icon-plus-sign">
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" {{action my_action my_argument}}> My Action </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        {{/each}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since this HTML code is not immediately available when the page is loaded, but is loaded dynamically later, after the data is loaded with an AJAX request and the `content` variable is populated, the `dropdown` is not working properly: it's not closing when the `action` link is clicked.

I understand that to make this work, I need to do something like this after the `dropdown` element is in the DOM:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

In **Emberjs**, is there a callback or a place where I could do that, *after* the data has been added to the DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of call should be used in the views, in the `didInsertElement` function.
see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement

I know there are some other SO questions/answers about this... but I'm too lazy to search for you :p